# Identifying a specific Latex template

Tags: templates

could you please help my identify the template that is used in many publications about CS / AI research such as in the following document:

http://cs.stanford.edu/~jsteinhardt/publications/nested-gamma/abstract.pdf

I would appreciate any help, since I think the template is very neat.

Comment: Hi and welcome, `article` with `geometry` to set the margins, `titling` to customize the title (or do it completely on your own, package `tgheros` (for the diagrams) and `tgtermes` (and its math font) to get the fonts in the document (well, actually better alternatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is a very well-known template in the machine learning community. It's the style required for the NIPS (Neural Information Processing Systems) conference (and workshops).

It's available here:
https://nips.cc/Conferences/2015/PaperInformation/StyleFiles

Answer (score 3):

As you may know, there is no general procedure to "reverse engineer" a LaTeX document.

I would proceed as follow:

- Is this article published? If so, is the journal / conference / proceedings imposing a style?

In that case, this paper was an abstract to [2011 NIPS Workshop on Bayesian Nonparametrics](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~rpa/nips2011npbayes.html). It was accepted, and lead to a poster presentation, but no style was imposed (from what I saw).

- What is the department of the authors? Do they propose a LaTeX template ?

In that case, it seems that neither the Department of Mathematics of the Massachusetts Institute of Technology, neither the Department of Engineering of the University of Cambridge offer a template.

- Can I find similar documents?

In that case, I could'nt find anything (except maybe [this paper](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v33/duvenaud14.pdf) and [another paper by Jacob Steinhardt](http://cs.stanford.edu/~jsteinhardt/publications/adainfer/paper.pdf)).

This leads to the conclusion that it looks like a custom style. Contact one of the two author, people are generally glad to share their tips and tricks concerning LaTeX.