# What is the template used in this document?

Tags: fonts, templates, book-design

What is the of the template and font, used in [this document](http://www.uni-graz.at/~clason/teaching/numa13/NuMaSkript.pdf)?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like `classicthesis.sty` ... If this is the case, it's not recommended to use it, due to a bunch of problems

Comment: If you have the pdf acrobat fonts menu or pdffonts tool will report the fonts used.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly (your sentence, `What is the of the template`, probably contains a mistake)? You might consider looking at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227367/34551) if you want to find the template, or at [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/34551) if you're willing to know more about the fonts.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Kannst du das von der Liste schießen durch kurze Antwort?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template looks like `classicthesis` but this only a guess - work. Please note that `classicthesis` is known for a bunch of problems and was not maintained for a long time.

Comment: This indeed looks like a bad derivative of classicthesis. But what makes you say "known for a bunch of problems", what problems are you specifically referring to?  Every latex package has a list of problems (with other packages), and I don't see "do not use"  being said for any of them. Classicthesis works. More than 5o theses get published every year in classic thesis style.