# Identifying a template for a scientific paper

Tags: packages, templates

I recently found this [paper](http://www.miketipping.com/papers/met-mlbayes.pdf) and I very much like the layout. Before contacting the author or trying to roll my own, does anyone know whether this is a publicly-available package?

[image]

The `miketipping.com` logo at the top right suggests it is not, but maybe this was just a simple addition from the author.

Comment: Is an author modifed version of http://bmvc2014.cs.nott.ac.uk/resources/bmvc2014CameraReady.zip

Comment: @YiannisLazarides thanks for the link, but it appears significantly different to me... Are you sure of that?

Comment: The author states the publication as Springer, you can search further there. But since he published it himself , he probably modified the template.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides DO you can/want to provide an answer or do we close as off-topic?

Comment: @Johannes_B why would you close this question as off-topic?

Comment: There is an indefinit amount of ways to achieve a document like that. It is a bit like posting a picture of a stew dish asking for the exact recipe to get that image. It cannot be answered unless you happen to be the guy who cooked the meal and shot the image.

Comment: In my opinion, it is more like posting a picture of a big mac, and ask for the restaurant that sells them. It can be answered if you happen to be a guy who has been to McDonald's. [There are other questions like this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227348), but anyway, feel free to close it if you think it is off-topic.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am not providing an answer, maybe it should be closed.

Comment: @lum If its the advertisement picture, maybe. But have you seen a real burger? They often look like *bluurb*. If its one of the big chains, you might have a chance, but there are soooo many different burgers out there. The chance of a *right* answer is close to nil. Since this is a place of questions and answers, a question without a possible answer is a bit useless (in my point of view). But it can stay open of course. This is a multi-million network, they have enough space for a few more questions ;-)